# ssl needs on the server for all paypal related api service?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

As per the paypal security upgrade on Jan 17th 2016 they are saying that the server needs to be installed with a ssl server with ssl of algorithm SHA-256 and the certificate needs to verify with a G5 ROOT certificate. But my doubt here previusly i can test the paypal sandbox payment in my localhost(a server without https) and it was worked perfectly. But as per the new upgrade from the paypal team is there any option to check the api service in sandbox in a http server(may be on localhost). When i try this i got a handshake_failure exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my mistake and finally i understood that ssl not needed. When i have update the paypal sdk jar to 1.4 the issue cleared.